# What was the last riddle set by Morgan le Fay?

Tags: stargate, stargate-sg1

In *Stargate SG-1* season 10 episode *The Quest (part 1)*, the last riddle set by Morgan le Fay in the cave system protecting the Sangraal is incompletely translated. From [the transcript](http://www.stargate-sg1-solutions.com/wiki/10.10_%22The_Quest_Part_1%22_Transcript):

> DANIEL (translating) Battle-scarred in times of strife. Resistant to…
>   resistant to…
>
> VALA To what?
>
> DANIEL Uh, I don't know. I— I can't translate this section of the
>   text.
>
> VALA Nevertheless, battle-scarred would suggest…
>
> ADRIA Contagia!

Was the full riddle ever revealed? Did anyone manage to Jeopardy it?

[This Yahoo! Answers post](https://au.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20090124224247AAWBrlC) suggests the answer could mean *shield* or *illness*.

Comment: Contegia means shield in Latin which would fit nicely with Ventio for wind (Ventus) and Clavio for key (Clavis). A shield is scarred in battle.

Comment: I am going to trust @Richard with the latin and impressive deduction hypothesis; but no it is never revealed. That dialogue is all we got. I always assumed that Adria was reading along with Daniel and translated it herself to know the rest of the riddle or that through Ori means she knew the answer already.

Comment: It's been established in-universe that Latin is a derivation of Ancient, and we can recognise many Ancient words as being somewhat like their Latin counterparts.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### The riddle was never revealed in full, so we have to work backwards from the answer

It is established that classical Latin is derived from Ancient, so they share a number of words. So figuring out the riddle will first involve figuring out the meaning of "Contagia".

It's quite likely that the word is different in Ancient than it is in Latin. As Valorum pointed out in the comments, the earlier riddles had the answers "ventio" (ventus, meaning wind) and "clavio" (clavis, meaning key)*, which were nouns.

The word as-is is one of [several plural conjugations](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/contagium#Latin) for the Latin word "[contagio](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/contagio#Latin)", meaning "touch" or "contact". This doesn't seem to fit with the riddle though, as it's not clear how touches can be battle-scarred.

However, the Oxford Latin Dictionary [translates the word](https://www.latin-dictionary.net/definition/13639/contagio-contagionis) as "disease" (in reference to many diseases being transmitted through physical contact). This reflects the modern word "contagion", and is pretty close to spelling of the riddle answer "contagia".

### Therefore, I think the answer is "disease".

This seems to fit with the riddle:

> Battle-scarred in times of strife

Diseases are often rampant during wartime due to injuries, the transport of troops from foreign regions, and the logistical challenges of fighting.

> Resistant to…

Diseases can also become resistant to treatments; there are often concerns of bacteria or viruses mutating to become immune to treatments.

The full riddle itself was never revealed. Perhaps the full statement was something along the lines of "Resistant to being wiped out" or something along those lines, referring to the tenacity of diseases.

### But how did they know the answer?

Note that Adria, the leader of the Ori, was the one who provided the answer. How did the Ori begin their war on our galaxy? With the vast spreading of disease, which we saw quite prominently on Earth during the Season 9 two-parter "The Fourth Horseman". Since the riddle said it was something that is battle-scarred that is resistant, that was probably something prominent on her mind.

<sub>* Valorum speculated that it could be a variation on the verb "[contego](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/contego)" (note that the "a" changes to an "e"), meaning conceal, protect, clothe, bury, or entomb. Valorum speculated that since the other two answers were nouns, this might be "protection", or more concretely, "a shield". However, Latin doesn't have a noun form of this word (i.e. it is only used as a verb), so I disagree and think that "contagio" is a more likely choice.</sub>

Comment: Hm... the "shield" meaning vastly better fits the clues, though. I like it!

Comment: It might fit, but I don't think that the Latin supports it, since it's a more distant word. Still, glad you appreciate my analysis!

Comment: I think it differs only within the margin of how Ancient and Latin diverged.

Comment: "Con Tegimena" (accusative) in Latin means "with body armor". I  can't find a reference for "contegia" meaning "shield" in Latin. It is the nominative or accusative plural for "contagium", meaning "touch" or "contact", and by extension "disease spread by contact". As to the riddle, the writers may have just taken it from: "In Battle-scars and times of strife, resistant to the most brutal of strikes. I live among men and children alike. But not once have you seen me walk past you.
But my biggest fear grows with things left overnight. Who am I?"