# Where does this quote come from?

Tags: stargate, stargate-sg1

In another question ([What was the last riddle set by Morgan le Fay?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/123607/what-was-the-last-riddle-set-by-morgan-le-fay)) [@Codosaur](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/103926/codosaur) said that,

> As to the riddle, the writers may have just taken it from: *"In Battle-scars and times of strife, resistant to the most brutal of strikes. I live among men and children alike. But not once have you seen me walk past you. But my biggest fear grows with things left overnight. Who am I?"*

What is the context of this quote that it was taken from? Where did this come from? To what was [@Codosaur](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/103926/codosaur) referring to with that quote?

Comment: There are no PMs in the StackExchange system. This is not a chat system, it is a Q&A site. However, you can post your own comment to Thunderforge's answer asking Codosaur where the quote came from.

Comment: I thought my answer was pretty much comprehensive. Is there anything else you'd want to see before considering an acceptance?

Answer (score 5):

The quote he's referring to appears to be from [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/riddles/comments/6usr9h/my_riddle/). User Circuitslave posted it in 2017 as a riddle of the day.

The back end of the riddle appears to be an original creation, whereas the front part is taken almost directly from the Stargate episode [The Quest, Part I](https://stargate.fandom.com/wiki/The_Quest,_Part_1)

> "Battle-scarred in times of strife. Resistant to"

It seems highly unlikely that the writers of a Stargate episode written in 2005 would have drawn their inspiration from a Reddit post from 2017.

Comment: Although we know the Stargate can be used for time travel... :)